# jquery tag it send content

Tags: php, jquery, sql, tags

I try this jquery tag http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

my code:

```
<ul id="myTags"></ul> 
<textarea id="tagsend" style="display:none" rows="30" cols="30" name="tags"></textarea>
```

and submit btn:

```
<input name="invia" type="submit" class="sendnewsbtn" value="Invia" onclick="document.getElementById('tagsend').innerHTML = getElementById('myTags').innerHTML";>
```

on submit.php:

```
$taginput = $_POST["tags"];
 $tagarray = explode(",",$taginput);
    for($i=0;$i<count($tagarray);$i++){
         $usetag = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(ltrim(rtrim($tagarray[$i]))));
         if($usetag == "") continue;
                 $querytag = "INSERT INTO tags (link_id,tag) VALUES ('$rowid','$usetag')";
                      mysql_query($querytag);
                }
```

the result of record on mysql table is: `<li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state`

and not the tags sent.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid markup here:

```
<input name="invia" type="submit" class="sendnewsbtn" value="Invia"
       onclick="document.getElementById('tagsend').innerHTML =
       getElementById('myTags').innerHTML";>
   // ^--missing document here------------^----';' outside here
```

try with this one:

```
    <input name="invia" type="submit" class="sendnewsbtn" value="Invia"
       onclick="document.getElementById('tagsend').innerHTML =
       document.getElementById('myTags').innerHTML;">
```

Comment: same result. anyway the single tags will be inside <li> such this <ul id="myTags">
    <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->
    <li>Tag1</li>
    <li>Tag2</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

If You use jQuery You can change this

```
<input name="invia" type="submit" class="sendnewsbtn" value="Invia" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('tagsend').innerHTML = getElementById('myTags').innerHTML";>
```

on this

```
<input name="invia" type="submit" class="sendnewsbtn" value="Invia"
    onclick="$('textarea#tagsend').html($('#myTags').html())">
```